# Errors while importing Operator (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I am a little confused after a couple attempts while importing Operator and receiving errors.  Along with a couple of examples, I've shared a python doc link for reference below.

What I'm expecting to happen below is that `operator` will run the product and multiply 3 * 4 in the `data` list which the answer will start `[3, 12....]` then multiply 12 by the next element '6' to give, `[3, 12, 72...]`.  However importing Operator here isn't working as expected?

The Output I'm expecting for this problem is:

```
[3, 12, 72, 144, 144, 1296, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Running the below code in [PythonTutor.com](https://pythontutor.com) gives me an Error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'operator'
```

```
from itertools import operator

data = [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 7, 5, 8]
list(accumulate(data, operator.mul))
```

I've gotten the same type of error running this in Jupyter notebook:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bc61652bebb8> in <module>
----> 1 from itertools import operator
      2 
      3 data = [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 7, 5, 8]
      4 list(accumulate(data, operator.mul))

ImportError: cannot import name 'operator' from 'itertools' (unknown location)
```

I've spelled check about 100 times and I've ran these on both PythonTutor and Jupyter NB, and both are giving me errors - can this be an issue with `itertools`?

Below is from The Python Docs. I'm using the first case:

```
operator.mul(a, b)
```

I'll share for your reference: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
   ----> operator.mul(a, b)
    operator.__mul__(a, b)
    Return a * b, for a and b numbers.
```

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share with us what's your expected output?  And what you tried to achieve here?  Afraid this could  be an https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) is its own module, not part of `itertools`:

```
import itertools
import operator
```

Note that `itertools.accumulate` doesn't modify the iterable it is given. It returns a new object which you are not using above. Consider assigning it to a new variable:

```
data = [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 9, 0, 7, 5, 8]
accumulated_list = list(itertools.accumulate(data, operator.mul))
```